# How do I update fields in a first table using inner join to a second table where field in first table is null?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to update two fields in a table using an inner join from a second table, but only on rows in the first table where one of the fields is not populated (e.g null) (shown below). Here is the query I'm trying to use.

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;
UPDATE mydb.mbb_pla_inputs pl
INNER JOIN mydb.class_nm_lookup_table class ON pl.RMS_CLASS_NM = class.RMS_CLASS_NM 
SET pl.campaign_name = class.campaign, pl.ad_group_name = class.ad_group
WHERE pl.campaign_name IS NULL;
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 1;
```

However it doesn't seem to be updating the records.  Can anyone help me?

```
mydb.mbb_pla_inputs

# idmbb_pla_inputs, insertion_timestamp, RMS_CLASS_NM, SKU_NUM, PRODUCT_GROUP, TRACKING_TEMPLATE, MAX_CPC, BID_DATE, campaign_name, ad_group_name
205607, 2018-04-30 08:23:59, Ab Rollers Core, 10166704, * / Item ID='10166704', {unescapedlpurl}&cmp=KNC-[*EngineAccountType*]:[*Campaign*]:[*Adgroup*]:10166704, , 2017-01-01 00:00:00, , 
205608, 2018-04-30 08:23:59, Ab Rollers Core, 10195301, * / Item ID='10195301', {unescapedlpurl}&cmp=KNC-[*EngineAccountType*]:[*Campaign*]:[*Adgroup*]:10195301, , 2017-01-01 00:00:00, , 
205609, 2018-04-30 08:23:59, Ab Rollers Core, 10195303, * / Item ID='10195303', {unescapedlpurl}&cmp=KNC-[*EngineAccountType*]:[*Campaign*]:[*Adgroup*]:10195303, , 2017-01-01 00:00:00, , 
205610, 2018-04-30 08:23:59, Ab Rollers Core, 10261308, * / Item ID='10261308', {unescapedlpurl}&cmp=KNC-[*EngineAccountType*]:[*Campaign*]:[*Adgroup*]:10261308, , 2017-01-01 00:00:00, , 
205611, 2018-04-30 08:23:59, Ab Rollers Core, 10261336, * / Item ID='10261336', {unescapedlpurl}&cmp=KNC-[*EngineAccountType*]:[*Campaign*]:[*Adgroup*]:10261336, , 2017-01-01 00:00:00, , 
205612, 2018-04-30 08:23:59, Ab Rollers Core, 10266581, * / Item ID='10266581', {unescapedlpurl}&cmp=KNC-[*EngineAccountType*]:[*Campaign*]:[*Adgroup*]:10266581, , 2017-01-01 00:00:00, , 
205613, 2018-04-30 08:23:59, Ab Rollers Core, 10266591, * / Item ID='10266591', {unescapedlpurl}&cmp=KNC-[*EngineAccountType*]:[*Campaign*]:[*Adgroup*]:10266591, , 2017-01-01 00:00:00, , 


mydb.campaigns
# idpla_campaigns, RMS_CLASS_NM, campaign, ad_group, insertion_timestamp
'1', 'RMS_CLASS_NM', 'CAMPAIGN', 'AD_GROUP', '2018-04-02 15:16:26'
'2', 'CARDIO EQUIPMENT', 'mvp_cardio', 'Cardio', '2018-04-02 15:16:26'
'3', 'BABY MONITORS', 'mvp_baby', 'Baby', '2018-04-02 15:16:26'
'4', 'CAR SEATS', 'mvp_baby', 'Baby', '2018-04-02 15:16:26'
'5', 'NURSERY & DECOR', 'mvp_baby', 'Baby', '2018-04-02 15:16:26'
```

Comment: Are you sure campaign_name is NULL? Or is it maybe an empty string? From your tables it is unclear. Also, indicate which table is which in your question.

Comment: Hi luksch,
I'm pretty sure the field is filled with nulls, because they show up as nulls in the mysql editor after executing a query. Also, if I do just a straight SELECT statement on the first table for records where the campaign_name field is null it returns the correct rows.  

I'll add table titles.  They are sort of in the tables in the form of the primary key name, but I'll make it more explicit.

Comment: Does the INNER JOIN without the update command execute weill and bring all results that you want to update?

Comment: SELECT * FROM  mydb.mbb_pla_inputs pl WHERE pl.campaign_name IS NULL; gives me all the rows I want.  

When I do  

SELECT * FROM  mydb.mbb_pla_inputs pl WHERE pl.campaign_name IS NULL;
INNER JOIN mydb.class_nm_lookup_table class ON pl.RMS_CLASS_NM = class.RMS_CLASS_NM  WHERE pl.campaign_name = "";

It returns zero rows. I presume this is because it's applying the WHERE condition during the SET command but without actually executing the SET.

Comment: Should `mydb.campaigns` be `mydb.class_nm_lookup_table`?

Comment: There are no matches between `RMS_CLASS_NM` in the two tables.

Comment: It's `Ab Rollers Core` in all the rows in the first table, that doesn't appear anywhere in the second table.

Comment: `select * from mbb_pla_inputs pl
INNER JOIN class_nm_lookup_table class ON pl.RMS_CLASS_NM = class.RMS_CLASS_NM` returns no rows.

Comment: Hi Barmar,
Yeah, those are just a small number of records to show the structure.  If I run that query on the full data set it returns rows.  That's not the issue.